# Disabling ajax and url hashing for certain links in jquery mobile 1.4.5

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I've got a couple php pages that do some header manipulation (redirecting, attachment downloads, etc) on my site, and I've noticed that jquery mobile's ajax handling of links is messing them up. How can I disable ajax, url hashing and anything else jquery mobile does to those links so that they allow the php scripts to work as expected?

Some thing's I've tried:

Adding `data-ajax="false"` to the links. This seems to disable the nice page transition, but the php pages are not loading as expected with the modified headers.

Adding this code before loading jquery mobile:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
     $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

This works! But unfortunately disables ajax for all links, which is not the desired behavior...

I tried this as per another stackoverflow answer:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $('.disable-ajax').click(function(event){
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
});
```

Then I added the "disable-ajax" class to the links. No change. I've tried playing with other configuration options as well such as

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
$.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
```

But I haven't had any success. Any ideas?

Comment: Add `rel="external"` to anchors, to load pages without ajax.

Comment: Thanks, tried that too. And adding targets

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out... I think it has to do with the way I'm using the site in a subdirectory...

Comment: try `$(document).on("pagecreate", function () { $('.disable-ajax').on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); location.href = $(this).attr("href"); });  });`